# Float left for text and image?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Every time I put this, it never works. What am I doing? I'm trying to get the moderpanel under the image. but it stays on the right side instead.

```
<img src="$THUMBNAIL_URL$" align="left" />
 <div id="photo-information"> <strong>Description:</strong>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="moderPanel" style="float:left;" >
 $MODER_PANEL$
```

Comment: align is a deprecated attribute in HTML 4.01, you should stop using that and replace it with CSS (there's no strict equivalent though, but I find it another reason not to use it: it doesn't mix well with CSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this align left off your image.
It works.
See:

```
<img src="$THUMBNAIL_URL$" />
<div id="photo-information"> <strong>Description:</strong></div>
<br />
<div class="moderPanel" style="float:left">
$MODER_PANEL$
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the image has a float or something?

try to do this, see if this works:

```
<img src="$THUMBNAIL_URL$" align="left" />
 <div id="photo-information"> <strong>Description:</strong>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div style="clear:both"></div>   <------------ clears the previous floats...
 <div class="moderPanel" style="float:left;" >
 $MODER_PANEL$
```